# How to fire an event after data inserted using boot? (laravel)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I am finding a way to somewhat fire an event after the Eloquent has finished creating.

Here's my code in `Branch` model:

```
class Branch extends Model
{
    //some code here

    public static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        self::created(function (HistoryLog $model) { 
            $model->tag = 'Created';
            $model->description = 'This branch was created by '. ucwords(auth()->user()->name());
            $model->save();
        });
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is, I want to create a *history_log* after branch was created. 
But this code returns an error:

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Argument 1 passed to
>        App\Vehicle::App{closure}() must be an instance of App\HistoryLog, instance of
>        App\Vehicle given, called in D:\document\My Documents\optodph\vendor\laravel\fr
>       amework\src\Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher.php on line 347

Can someone point out to me what's wrong with that code? And what's the right way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel way to do this.

Create an Observer:

```
php artisan make:observer BranchObserver --model=Branch
```

Add your logic to the Observer:

```
<?php

namespace App\Observers;

use App\Branch;

class BranchObserver
{
    /**
     * Handle the Branch "created" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Branch  $branch
     * @return void
     */
    public function created(Branch $branch)
    {
        // Add your logic here
    }
}
```

Register it in `AppServiceProvider`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Branch;
use App\Observers\BranchObserver;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Branch::observe(BranchObserver::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$model is a new record created. Is an instance of `App\Vehicle` not a `App\HistoryLog`.

Working code might look like this:

```
class Vehicle extends Model
{
    //some code here

    public static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        self::created(function ($model) { 
            App\HistoryLog::create([...]);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: this is actually working. But I think **laravel observers** are the right way. Thanks for your response bro

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this with Eloquent Observers https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#observers